# How to minimize an undecorated JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I want to minimize a `JFrame`?

Note: `JFrame` is set `undecorated` to true in Netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to set minimize action for JFrame when clicked a JButton?

Not sure why you want to do this. The frame already has to button to click. Why do you need another button?

Anyway to change the state of the frame:

```
frame.setExtendedState( JFrame.ICONIFIED );
```